# Como puedo convertir un for en una promise NODEJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

soy nuevo usando este lenguaje, y me complica bastante su logica asincrona, es por eso que quisiera ayuda.

Este es mi codigo, necesito hacer una promesa en el segundo FOR dentro del ELSE, para que termine antes de enviar el RESOLVE(ciudades), ya que al ser asincrono me manda ciudades como esta inicializada y no modificada como deberia.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const todoRoutes = express.Router();
const PORT = 4000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

function algo(x) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // CONEXION A REDIS USANDO PUERTO POR DEFECTO
        var redis = require('redis');
        var client = redis.createClient(); //crear nuevo cliente
        client.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('connected');
        });
        if (Math.random(0, 1) < 0.1) {
            console.log("FALLLLOOOOO!!!!");
            res.send("{'status':'failed', 'message':'problem'}");
        } else {
            /* INGRESAR COORDENADAS DE LAS CIUDADES A LA BD */
            /* Coordenadas */
            var ciudades = [{
                id: 'Santiago',
                Latitud: -33.459999,
                Longitud: -70.639999,
                Temperatura: `0`,
                Hora: `0`
            }, {
                id: 'Zurich',
                Latitud: 47.458057,
                Longitud: 8.547778,
                Temperatura: `0`,
                Hora: `0`
            }, {
                id: 'Auckland',
                Latitud: -36.849998,
                Longitud: 174.770004,
                Temperatura: `0`,
                Hora: `0`
            }, {
                id: 'Sydney',
                Latitud: -33.869999,
                Longitud: 151.210007,
                Temperatura: `0`,
                Hora: `0`
            }, {
                id: 'Londres',
                Latitud: 10.630000,
                Longitud: -63.310001,
                Temperatura: `0`,
                Hora: `0`
            }, {
                id: 'Georgia',
                Latitud: -33.749001,
                Longitud: -84.387978,
                Temperatura: `0`,
                Hora: `0`
            }];
            for (let i = 0; i < ciudades.length; i++) {
                client.hset(`${ciudades[i].id}`, "Lat", `${ciudades[i].Latitud}`, "Lon", `${ciudades[i].Longitud}`, "Temp", "0", "Hora", "0");
                client.hgetall(`${ciudades[i].id}`, function(err, value) {
                    // console.log(value);
                });
            }
            // var menssage=`holaaaa`;
            for (let i = 0; i < ciudades.length; i++) {
                /* PARA UNA CIUDAD IR POR TEMPERATURA Y TIEMPO */
                /* sacar lat y lon de BD */
                client.hgetall(`${ciudades[i].id}`, function(err, value) {
                    var lat = value.Lat;
                    var lon = value.Lon;
                    var url = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/081c5fbf75a1097dab2cca9a11e271dc/${lat},${lon}`
                        // console.log(url);
                    const axios = require('axios');
                    const apiclima = axios.create({
                        baseURL: url,
                    });
                    apiclima.get()
                        .then(resp => {
                            var temp = (((resp.data.currently.temperature - 32) * (5 / 9)))
                            var date = new Date(resp.data.currently.time * 1000)
                            var tiempo = `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
                            /* GUARDAR EN BD */
                            client.hset(`${ciudades[i].id}`, "Lat", `${ciudades[i].Latitud}`, "Lon", `${ciudades[i].Longitud}`, "Temp", `${temp}`, "Hora", `${tiempo}`);
                            // console.log(`${ciudades[i].id}`, "Lat", `${ciudades[i].Latitud}`, "Lon", `${ciudades[i].Longitud}`, "Temp", `${temp}`, "Hora", `${tiempo}`);
                            client.hgetall(`${ciudades[i].id}`, function(err, value) {
                            // console.log(ciudades[i].id);                            
                            // console.log(value.Lat);
                            ciudades[i].Temperatura=value.Temp;
                            ciudades[i].Hora=value.Hora;
                            console.log("PUTOOOO");
                            console.log(ciudades[i]);
                            });
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log('ERROOORRRR', err.message);
                        })
                });
            }
            console.log("AQUI VOY");
            console.log(ciudades);
            resolve(ciudades);
        }       
    });
}

todoRoutes.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
    algo(5).then((resp) => {
        console.log("recibiendo desde React y ejecutando en node1");
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.send(resp)
        res.end()
      });
});

    app.use('/', todoRoutes);
    app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
    });
```

Hice un intento y seria el siguiente

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const todoRoutes = express.Router();
const PORT = 4000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
function llenado(y){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        var ciudades=[null];
        // CONEXION A REDIS USANDO PUERTO POR DEFECTO
        var redis = require('redis');
        var client = redis.createClient(); //crear nuevo cliente
        client.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('connected');
        });
        for (let i = 0; i < ciudades.length; i++) {
            /* PARA UNA CIUDAD IR POR TEMPERATURA Y TIEMPO */
            /* sacar lat y lon de BD */
            client.hgetall(`${ciudades[i].id}`, function(err, value) {
                var lat = value.Lat;
                var lon = value.Lon;
                var url = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/081c5fbf75a1097dab2cca9a11e271dc/${lat},${lon}`
                    // console.log(url);
                const axios = require('axios');
                const apiclima = axios.create({
                    baseURL: url,
                });
                apiclima.get()
                    .then(resp => {
                        var temp = (((resp.data.currently.temperature - 32) * (5 / 9)))
                        var date = new Date(resp.data.currently.time * 1000)
                        var tiempo = `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
                        /* GUARDAR EN BD */
                        client.hset(`${ciudades[i].id}`, "Lat", `${ciudades[i].Latitud}`, "Lon", `${ciudades[i].Longitud}`, "Temp", `${temp}`, "Hora", `${tiempo}`);
                        // console.log(`${ciudades[i].id}`, "Lat", `${ciudades[i].Latitud}`, "Lon", `${ciudades[i].Longitud}`, "Temp", `${temp}`, "Hora", `${tiempo}`);
                        client.hgetall(`${ciudades[i].id}`, function(err, value) {
                        // console.log(ciudades[i].id);                            
                        // console.log(value.Lat);
                        ciudades[i].Temperatura=value.Temp;
                        ciudades[i].Hora=value.Hora;
                        console.log(ciudades[i]);
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log('ERROOORRRR', err.message);
                    })
            });
        }
        resolve(ciudades);
        console.log(`cacaaaa ${ciudades}`)
    })
}
function algo(x) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // CONEXION A REDIS USANDO PUERTO POR DEFECTO
        var redis = require('redis');
        var client = redis.createClient(); //crear nuevo cliente
        client.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('connected');
        });
        if (Math.random(0, 1) < 0.1) {
            console.log("FALLLLOOOOO!!!!");
            res.send("{'status':'failed', 'message':'problem'}");
        } else {
            /* INGRESAR COORDENADAS DE LAS CIUDADES A LA BD */
            /* Coordenadas */
            let ciudades = [{
                id: 'Santiago',
                Latitud: -33.459999,
                Longitud: -70.639999,
                Temperatura: `0`,
                Hora: `0`
            }, {
                id: 'Zurich',
                Latitud: 47.458057,
                Longitud: 8.547778,
                Temperatura: `0`,
                Hora: `0`
            }, {
                id: 'Auckland',
                Latitud: -36.849998,
                Longitud: 174.770004,
                Temperatura: `0`,
                Hora: `0`
            }, {
                id: 'Sydney',
                Latitud: -33.869999,
                Longitud: 151.210007,
                Temperatura: `0`,
                Hora: `0`
            }, {
                id: 'Londres',
                Latitud: 10.630000,
                Longitud: -63.310001,
                Temperatura: `0`,
                Hora: `0`
            }, {
                id: 'Georgia',
                Latitud: -33.749001,
                Longitud: -84.387978,
                Temperatura: `0`,
                Hora: `0`
            }];
            for (let i = 0; i < ciudades.length; i++) {
                client.hset(`${ciudades[i].id}`, "Lat", `${ciudades[i].Latitud}`, "Lon", `${ciudades[i].Longitud}`, "Temp", "0", "Hora", "0");
                client.hgetall(`${ciudades[i].id}`, function(err, value) {
                    // console.log(value);
                });
            }
            // var menssage=`holaaaa`;
            array = llenado(ciudades);
            console.log(array);
            resolve(array);
        }       
    });
}

todoRoutes.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
    algo(5).then((resp) => {
        console.log("recibiendo desde React y ejecutando en node1");
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.send(resp)
        res.end()
      });
});

    app.use('/', todoRoutes);
    app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
    });
```

Esto debe conectarse a reactjs y asi poder mostrar los datos en una web, esta consumiendo una api y llenando una BD redis alojada en un docker.
Esto para mi es totalmente nuevo, nunca habia usado niuna de estas herramientas.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido. Para esperar a que todas las peticiones HTTP terminen, podés almacenar sus promesas en un `array` y utilizar [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Esté método te retona un objeto `Promise`, dentro del método `then` de este objeto podrías usar el `resolve` del que vos estás retronando..... Alguna otra persona podría ayudarte con el código porque en estos momentos no tengo un ambiente de NodeJS

Comment: Gracias, intentare ver como se hace. Saludos. C: